# Too many positional (i.e. '$') when trying to update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update an element.

//Schema

```
var SurveySchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    form: [{
            sections: [ // each section's a page
                {
                    name: String,
                    description: String,
                    input: {
                        _type: String,
                        contents: [
                            {
                                _id: false,
                                "text": String,
                                "value": String
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
});
```

// My Json

```
{
    "_id": "58fe27e0e340671c9859c995",
    "__v": 0,
    "form": [
    {
        "_id": "58fe2b1de437791cd02b9a8c",
        "sections": [
            {
                "_id": "58fe2b1de437791cd02b9a8d",
                "input": {
                    "_type": "radio"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "58fe2ca32470711c586d6b6e",
        "sections": []
    }
    ]
}
```

// Update

```
var save = function(req, res) {
    var survey = {};
    survey.id = req.params.surveyId; // 58fe27e0e340671c9859c995
    survey.form_id = req.params.formId; // 58fe2b1de437791cd02b9a8c

    Survey.update(
        { _id: survey.id, // 58fe27e0e340671c9859c995
          'form._id': survey.form_id // 58fe2b1de437791cd02b9a8c
         },  
        {'$set': {
           'form.$.sections.$.input._type': 'checkbox'
        }},
        {safe: true, upsert: true},
        function(err, model) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(model);
        }
    );
};
```

I want to change the `input._type` for a new value: `'checkbox'` on the id: `_id: 58fe2b1de437791cd02b9a8c`, but I keep receiving this error message: `"Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'form.$.sections.$.input._type'"` and the app crashes.

Comment: This is a sign that you are doing something you should be doing. [See doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays)

Comment: Could you post your mongoose schema

Comment: @DanGreen-Leipciger The Schema was posted. If you want to give some tips, be free to say.

Comment: There is no way to perform this query with mongodb. They have an opened issue about it, you can not have more than one $ or $N elements in an update query.

Comment: @JulienTASSIN what's the better way to update? using indexes? If I know the index of the form and the sections, should I update using the index? like: ``'form.'+ indexForm + '.sections.' + sectionID + '.input._type': 'checkbox'``

Comment: @Jose : one way could be to load the `Survey` with mongoose update it with node and `.save()` it

Comment: @JoseMaximilian  If this solved your problem, could you upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a different schema for each distinct type of element you have (section, input)

Give this a shot:

```js
const surveySchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  sections: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Section'
    }
  ]
});

const sectionSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  contents: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Input'
    }
  ]
});

const inputSchema = new Schema({
  text: String,
  value: String,
  _type: String
});

const Input = mongoose.model('Input', inputSchema);
const Section = mongoose.model('Section', sectionSchema);
const Survey = mongoose.model('Survey', surveySchema);
```

Then to update it

```
Input.update({ _id: id }, { $set: { _type: 'checkbox' }});
```

You can find more on Mongoose schema [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

You can find more on Mongoose relationships [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: @Jose, this should work, but why would you even want to do this?

Comment: Is there a better way to update the input type? I'm a beginner using Node.js.

Comment: You should probably have a collection of input documents. Then the form could have a relationship to all of the inputs

Comment: @DanGreen-Leipciger Correct me if I'm wrong, but your``sectionSchema`` only allows one page survey. If I want multiple pages (each section's a page), I would need to wrap the section Schema with ``[]``, it isn't?

Comment: @JoseMaximilian, Take a look now. If it works for you, please consider upvoting the answer